# Validate URL domain using regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to validate a URL in multiple formats.
EG:

```
https://www.google.com OK
http://www.google.com  OK
www.google.com     OK
htt://www.google.com
://www.google.com
https://google.com  OK
http\\www.google.com
http:\\www.google.com
http:\\www.google.com
http://computerName/abc/MenuItems.aspx OK
https://computerName/abc/MenuItems.aspx OK
http://www.a.com/abc/ms.aspx?Id=13&(Not.Licensed.For.Production)= OK
http://www.a.com/abc/ms.aspx?Id=13 OK
```

I'm using this regex

```
^(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?|www\.)[a-z0-9]+(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\-/\.]+)*(?::[0-9]{1,5})?(?:\/[a-z0-9]+)*(?:\.[a-z]{2,5})?$
```

But the last two items aren't ok. How can I also validate for urls without www and for eg.(.com)
I tried to removed the part (that I think validates the .com but without success.

It's almost working but found a new cases last two that don't work
Here's my sample https://regex101.com/r/w3dQSl/5

Comment: Try `^https?:\/\/[a-z0-9]+(?:[-.][a-z0-9]+)*(?::[0-9]{1,5})?(?:\/[a-z0-9]+)*(?:\.[a-z]{2,5})?$`  https://regex101.com/r/nQqxyy/1

Comment: just have one problem. this www.google.com is returning false and is a valid URL.

Comment: Then you could match either the http:// with optional www part or only the www part https://regex101.com/r/w3dQSl/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird found a new case that didn't work :( try to accomplish it but didn't work. will post the update regex101 next

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/w3dQSl/5

Comment: The added urls should or should not match?

Comment: @Thefourthbird the URL should match

Comment: Which ones whould also be matched? All last 3 of them? https://regex101.com/r/w3dQSl/5 The last item does match..

Comment: Which programming language are you using ? There may be a library that does the job so you don't have to reinvent the wheel

Comment: @Thefourthbird all the URL in that example are valid

Comment: @Luis Do you mean like this? `^https?:\/\/[a-z0-9]+(?:[-.][a-z0-9]+)*(?::[0-9]{1,5})?(?:\/[a-z0-9]+)*(?:\.[a-z]{2,5})(?:[?#]\S*)?$` https://regex101.com/r/GjpDa4/1

Comment: @Luis Or all of them https://regex101.com/r/mTE9QU/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example links, you could use

```
^https?:\/\/[a-z0-9]+(?:[-.][a-z0-9]+)*(?::[0-9]{1,5})?(?:\/[^\/\r\n]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(?:[?#]\S*)?$
```

The pattern will match:

- `^` Start of string
- `https?:\/\/` Match the protocol with optional s and `://`
- `[a-z0-9]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed
- `(?:[-.][a-z0-9]+)*` Repeat 0+ times any of the listed preceded by a `-` or `.`
- `(?::[0-9]{1,5})?` Optionally match `:` and 1-5 digits
- `(?:\/[^\/\r\n]+)*` Repeat 0+ times `/` and any char except `/`
- `\.[a-z]{2,5}` Match a `.` and 2-5 times a char a-z
- `(?:[?#]\S*)?` Optionally match either `?` or `#` and 0+ times any non whitespace char
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h8OFUB/1)

Answer (score -1):

You ought to think about which URLs you try to match, but for your examples, this does the job and is also simpler than the inital regex you provided:

```
^(https?://)?(www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9_\-/\.\?=\&\(\)]+$
```

Optionally you can make some of the groups non-capturing by adding `?:` after the opening parentheses.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ZOXhI-MU2p2igHyc)

Comment: @Luis if you want more help, you have to be more specific than that. the Debuggex Demo shows that the valid URLs in your example data are correctly matched (highlighted). If it doesn't work FOR YOU, you need to give more info on what goes wrong, what regex engine you are using etc. Before you do that, a downvote of my answer is hardly justified.

Comment: @Luis if you are referring to the example data of the regex101 sample, please note that all relevant question information (especially sample data) should be part of the post itself. To make those work as well, all you need to do is to extend the last character class with all permitted characters, i.e. in your case &, ?, (, ) -> [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ZOXhI-MU2p2igHyc)